# GIS open source for developer

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations

What do you recommend for coding using an open source software that is similar to ArcGIS runtime java SDK ?

Comment: Is Java a requirement?

Answer (score 1):

[OpenJUMP](http://www.openjump.org) is a relatively advanced open source desktop GIS software developed in Java. It certainly does not have all the functionalities of ArcGIS but it might be worth checking it. If you look for an equivalent to ArcGIS server, check [Geomajas](http://www.geomajas.org) or [geoserver](http://geoserver.org/).